# Recursive Lines Asterisks Python program

Tags: python

Program should print lines of asterisks on the screen, with the first line
containing one asterisk, the second line containing 2 asterisks, up to the nth
line which contains n asterisks.

Here's what I have so far, but is there a simpler way to do this?  I'd like to use `if`/`else` but haven't been able to make it work.

```
def show_asterisks(n):
    if (n > 0):
        show_asterisks(n-1)
    num = n
    str = ''
    while (num > 0):
        str += '*'
        num -= 1
        print(str)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: `print '\n'.join('*' * (i+1) for i in range(n))`

Comment: A slight optimization to @tobias_k code: `print '\n'.join('*' * (i) for i in range(1,n+1))`

Answer (score 1):

Recursion isn't required, but if you want to...

This solution is based on fact that Python sequences (including strings) may be multiplied by positive integer.

```
assert [1, 2] * 2 == [1, 2, 1, 2]
assert "qwe" * 3 == "qweqweqwe"
```

Solution is rather simple:

```
def print_asterisks(n):
    if (n > 1):
        print_asterisks(n-1)
    print "*" * n
```

Comment: I thought I was overthinking it!  Thank you so much for your time and assistance!

Comment: 1. asserting for such examples is rather redundant, you should rather print it so someone who does not know python can paste it to shell and see the result.  2. you should not use "()" in if statement, it is python, not c. 3. OP is clearly using python 3 (there are parenses over print) so this code will not run in his shell (print changed syntax between python 2 and 3)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the asterisk lines to be increasing

as line number = number of asterisks printed

```
def a(i, n):
    if i > n:  # check if we reached the end  and prevent infinite recursion
        return

    print(i*'*')
    a(i+1, n)  # call the function recursively with an incremented line number   


a(1,3) # (start linenumber, end linenumber)
```

gives

```
*
**
***
```

Comment: if STH: return else:STH2 is redundant, you should use  `if not STH: STH2` instead, so in your case: if i <= n: print ...

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest approach in python would be to use loop and the string multiplication operator

```
def show_asterisks(n):
    for i in range(n): # we perform loop n times
        print('*' * (i+1)) # each time we print i+1 '*', as i loop goes from 0
```

recursion is analogous

```
def show_asterisks(n):
    if n>1: # >0 is redundant!
        show_asterisks(n-1)
    print('*' * n)
```

Comment: Great!  I need to do this using recursion.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!!

Comment: recussion is completely analogous, up to some minor elements, see updated answer

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help!  I really appreciate it!